# Why doesn't this specific custom keyboard shortcut work in Finder?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder, macos-mojave

Using Automator, I made a service that launches calculator.app. In System Preferences > Keyboard, I created the keyboard shortcut CTRL-OPTION-COMMAND-C to trigger the service. This works great except when Finder is in focus.

The service does work through the Finder menu bar: Finder > Services > openCalculator (the name of my service). But my keyboard shortcut appears to do nothing in Finder.

If I change the keyboard shortcut to some other combination, it works.

I looked through Apple's list of Finder keyboard shortcuts to see if CTRL-OPTION-COMMAND-C was mapped to something else but it wasn't in the list.

I am using Mojave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it wouldn't work - there's no conflict I can think of.

If no-one can find a better solution, how about System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts
and just add it as a Finder menu command

Comment: I tested the App Shortcuts method and that works perfectly. Very strange!